# git: choose editor for a single command

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I want to do an interactive rebase. But this time there will be a lot of editing so I want to use different (graphical) editor. I don't want to set this editor permanently. I just need need it for this single rebase. Can I provide custom editor for this specific command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
GIT_EDITOR=vim git rebase ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

git -c core.editor=[editor] rebase [your args]